# js-xlsx: how to read local file without HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, excel, html

Im trying to use js-xlsx (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) to read a xlsx file that will be inputed by the user in a html file input. However I don't think the API that i'm developing this on supports HTML5 file handling. I'm getting: "$(...).addEventListener is not a function" in the console. The lib has an alternative for older browsers, but is an ajax call and I want to read a file inputed by the user on the fly.

Im using the functions available as examples in the github above.

Can I do this or I have to upload the file first to my server and then work on it with ajax?

Sorry if this is not a proper question, didnt seen to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Can't do it, need the newer API to access local filles without uploading them to a server

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes. I thought that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can read/write xlsx files without using third party plugins like js-xlsx.

However another method you can try is:

- Convert and save xlsx file as xml.
- Load xml file using ajax call and parse the structure.